# Regexp example for input accepting one or more spaces at the beginning and at the end but not in the middle

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms

regexp=/^([a-zA-Z0-9@_\s.#]+)$/;
I have tried this and not working

Comment: Add input data and desired output. More different examples are better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help you?

```
// no spaces in the middle at all
regexp=/^[ ]{,2}[^ ]+?[ ]{,2}$/

// no two spaces in the middle, one is ok
regexp=/^[ ]{,2}[^ ]+?(?!  )[^ ][ ]{,2}$/
```

Comment: Not working. Examples " ", "abc abc" should not work. "abc","  abc  " should work

Comment: Found it in stack overflow /^(?:\s*[@_.#]*[a-zA-Z0-9@_.#]{1,}[@_.#]*\s*)$/